# How to select a value from Devextreme dropdown with Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, dropdown, devextreme

I need to select values (any value from House_TypeList) from dropdown menu with NUnit or just pure selenium. .
They are not seen in HTML. 
I have tried select by xpath, by name, by span contains etc etc, I tried sending down key. I have waited for the element to become visible. I am out of ideas. Nothing works. I have not tried yet moving the cursor and trying to select it by that, but had a few problems implementing it and having in mind my luck, not really believing it will work either..

I am a beginner here, maybe I did some mistakes there. But I successfully managed any other inputs, buttons, navigation..

I have checked other similar questions, but could not find the answer that would work for me.

Is it even possible here?

Source:

```
<div class="dx-item dx-box-item" style="display: flex; min-height: auto; flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1;"
  <div class="dx-item-content dx-box-item-content" style="width: auto; height: auto; display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-basis: 0px; flex-grow: 1;">
    <div class="dx-first-col dx-last-col dx-field-item dx-field-item-required dx-col-0 dx-flex-layout dx-label-h-align">
      <label class="dx-field-item-label dx-field-item-label-location-left" for="dx_dx-...._typeId">
        <span class="dx-field-item-label-content" style="width: 159px;">
          <span class="dx-field-item-label-text">Type:</span>
          <span class="dx-field-item-required-mark">&nbsp;*</span>
        </span>
      </label>
      <div class="dx-field-item-content dx-field-item-content-location-right">
        <div class="dx-textbox dx-texteditor dx-texteditor-empty dx-dropdowneditor-button-visible dx-widget dx-dropdowneditor-field-clickable dx-dropdowneditor dx-selectbox dx-validator dx-visibility-change-handler" id="slb_HouseManagement_EditHouse_TypeList">
          <div class="dx-dropdowneditor-input-wrapper dx-selectbox-container">
            <input type="hidden" value="" name="typeId">
            <div class="dx-texteditor-container">
              <input autocomplete="off" id="dx_dx-4e..._typeId" class="dx-texteditor-input" aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="list" type="text" readonly="" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" role="combobox" aria-required="true">
              <div data-dx_placeholder="Select..." class="dx-placeholder"></div>
              <div class="dx-texteditor-buttons-container">
                <div class="dx-dropdowneditor-button dx-button-normal dx-widget" type="button">
                  <div class="dx-button-content">
                    <div class="dx-dropdowneditor-icon"></div>
                  </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. Found it in [Devextreme support](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t615025/cannot-select-an-item-in-selectbox-using-selenium), the user had a bit different problem, but it solved mine as well.

```
IWebElement selectedItem = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@role='option']/div[text()='Apartment']"));
selectedItem.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The DOM you have provided here does not contain any element for Lists. So I cannot share exact working code here. I will share few sample which you can update and use

With Selenium to select items from a list, you have two options to choose from:-

1. **Select Class**

Make an object of select class like below

```
 Select obj =new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("search-box")));
```

Then you can use several functions on this select obj

```
obj.selectByVisibleText("Apartment");
Or
obj.selectByIndex(2);
or
obj.selectByValue("Farmhouse");
```

You can also get all the element in a List and then work around that list

```
List <WebElement> myHouseList = obj.getOptions();

System.out.println(myHouseList.size());
```

2.**Actions Class**

```
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ele= driver.findElement(By.linkText("HouseList"));
  Actions act = new Actions(driver);
  act.moveToElement(ele).click();

  WebElement webele = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Apartment"));
  act.moveToElement(webele).click().build().perform();
```

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help, bet I still cannot select anything from the dropdown.
The thing is, even when the dropdown is selected and the options are visible, they do not appear in the source code (by watching through Chrome Inspector)
I cannot see any children of that input field.

Comment: When I click on it while Recording with selenium IDE, it is recorded as :
css=.dx-state-active > .dx-item-content

               OR                    

xpath=//div[20]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div             
OR   
xpath with id which is inconstant

Comment: can you share the exact loaded DOM of that webpage, so that I can replicate your issue, you are able to view list options on screen ? right ?